# How to update Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, upgrade

I don't understand the point: is it enough to apply all latest M1 patches to keep the Magento 1 up-to-date or do I need to download and install whole Magento 1 code package every time the new version becomes released?

The client wants to update to the latest Magento 1.9.4.2, now he has 1.9.4.1 installed. I see one patch was released after 1.9.4.1 release, do I need just to install it to have the code equal to 1.9.4.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

magento.com (https://magento.com/tech-resources/download) provides diff's for certain (sub-)versions. Unfortunately not all sub-releases are covered. *

Currently available are:

- 1.9.4.1 to 1.9.4.2
- 1.9.4.0 to 1.9.4.1
- 1.9.3.10 to 1.9.4.0
- 1.9.3.7 to 1.9.3.8
- 1.9.3.6 to 1.9.3.7

So in your case I'd go for applying the diff patch as following in order to change version from 1.9.4.1 to 1.9.4.2:

```
patch –p1 < CE-1.9.4.1-1.9.4.2-2019-06-19-04-26-18.diff
```

Also see

> **For patch files with the file extension .patch:**
>
> patch –p0 < patch_file_name.patch

from https://magento.com/tech-resources/download
 and note that there might be an issue when plainly relying on this information (see difference between `patch -p0 < ...` and `patch -p1 < ...` [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26501/when-patching-whats-the-difference-between-arguments-p0-and-p1?rq=1])

As mentioned correctly in the comments already: There is a major difference between Version upgrades (or version diffs) and SUPEE patches. Later ones wont come with features that may have been introduced in newer versions but in general contain security related changes only. However, some sub-versions may actually not introduce new features which means sometimes SUPEE patches are just as good as the newer release

A general guide can be found here (PDF guide):

> For further instructions, see: [Installing a Patch for Community Edition](https://info2.magento.com/rs/magentosoftware/images/Installing-a-Patch-for-Magento-Community-Edition.pdf)

from https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

*) As stated in the beginning, not all new versions come with diff's. Furthermore, let's say to go from 1.9.3.10 to 1.9.4.2, you'd have to patch your store 3 times (from 1.9.3.10 to 1.9.4.0 to 1.9.4.1 to 1.9.4.2). However, you may as well create your own diff files where you compare your current shop version with the latest available one. A short introduction to this is given in above liked unix.stackexchange.com-post.

Answer (score 1):

**You can not change your Magento current version by applying only patches.**

- If your client told you to move 1.9.4.1 to 1.9.4.2 then you have to upgrade your Magento version for the latest version.

**Patches:** In simple words, every patch is a package of modified core files that aims at fixing certain security issues that were discovered in Magento.

Comment: just to add patches do not include code improvements and functionalities of the newer versions

Comment: So where are the instructions for Magento 1 upgrade?